# Мобильное меню для сайта с прокруткой

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Как сделать подобное меню, чтобы меню было на весь экран и без возможности взаимодействия со страницей(кроме меню).

http://matec.optima.webprofy.ru/

На картинке наглядней или можно на сайте потыкать.
Есть мобильно меню. При открытие оно занимает 100% пространства экрана + появляется скрол для меню, если требуется.

[image: menu]

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. на сайте-примере меню реализовано на jQuery, то вот мой вариант:

```js
$('.menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-opened');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body.menu-opened {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f00;
}

header .menu-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}

header .menu-toggle span,
header .menu-toggle:before,
header .menu-toggle:after {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

header .menu-toggle:before {
  content: '';
  top: 4px;
}

header .menu-toggle:after {
  content: '';
  top: 16px;
}

header .menu-toggle span {
  top: 10px;
}

header .menu-menu-toggle:hover span {
  width: 22px;
}

body.menu-opened .menu-toggle span {
  opacity: 0;
}

body.menu-opened .menu-toggle:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}

body.menu-opened .menu-toggle:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 10px;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: #ccc
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body.menu-opened .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт #1</li>
    <li>Пункт #2</li>
    <li>Пункт #3</li>
    <li>Пункт #4</li>
    <li>Пункт #5</li>
    <li>Пункт #6</li>
    <li>Пункт #7</li>
    <li>Пункт #8</li>
    <li>Пункт #9</li>
    <li>Пункт #10</li>
    <li>Пункт #11</li>
    <li>Пункт #12</li>
    <li>Пункт #13</li>
    <li>Пункт #14</li>
    <li>Пункт #15</li>
    <li>Пункт #16</li>
    <li>Пункт #17</li>
    <li>Пункт #18</li>
    <li>Пункт #19</li>
    <li>Пункт #20</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
  accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
  magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
  Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum,
  qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident,
  similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod
  maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque
  earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, теперь понял как это работает. -_-

Answer (score 0):

```js
! function(e, t, n) {
  "use strict";
  var r = e.querySelectorAll(".menu"),
    a = function(e, t) {
      var n = t.getAttribute("aria-hidden");
      "false" == n ? (e.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false"),
          t.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true")) :
        (e.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true"),
          t.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false")
        );
    };
  [].forEach.call(r, function(e, t) {
    var n = e.nextElementSibling;
    e.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false"),
      e.setAttribute("aria-controls", "button-menu-" + t),
      n.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true"),
      n.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", "content-menu-" + t),
      n.setAttribute("tabindex", "0"),
      e.addEventListener("click", function() {
        return a(this, n), !1;
      }, !1), e.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        32 === e.which && (e.preventDefault(), a(this, n));
      }, !1);
  });
}(document, window);
```

```css
button.menu::before {
  content: '\2261';
  font-size: 2em;
}

button.menu[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '×';
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: brown;
  border-bottom: 1px solid Wheat;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: .8em 1.5em;
  color: LemonChiffon;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: Chocolate;
}

nav ul li a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

[aria-hidden="false"] {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  button.menu {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: table;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px dotted Wheat;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="menu"></button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Содержание</p>
</article>
```